# Creating blank row in dynamically created html table using angularJs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-mvc

I am adding blank row in my table , which is created dynamic by passing json object by using angular-JS.

I am not able to add blank row in table . Blank json row is not properly concatenating with existing json object/array.

How can i add new blank row on dynamically create table. Code provided below.

Here is my code :

```
//--CRUD.cshtml--//
<div ng-controller="crudController">
<div class="row">        
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    <table  class="table table-condensed">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>S.No.</th>
                <th ng-repeat="key in keys" ng-if="key!='UID'">{{key}}</th>
                <th>Edit</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody ng-init="GetDataForCrud()">
            <tr ng-repeat="data in datas" ng-include="getTeamplate(data)">
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs addnew pull-right" value="Add New" ng-click="AddNewRow()">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
//--CRUDDisplay.cshtml--//
<td>{{$index + 1}}</td>

                    <td ng-repeat="cell in data" ng-if="$index>0">{{cell}}</td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="Edit(data)">Edit</button></td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="Delete(data)">Delete</button></td>


//--CRUDEdit.cshtml--//
<td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
<td ng-repeat="cell in data" ng-if="$index>0"><input type="text" ng-model="cell" class="form-control input-sm"/></td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs" ng-click="Update(data)">Update</button></td>
                    <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" ng-click="Reset()">Reset</button></td> 


//--CRUDController.js--//
app.controller('crudController', function ($scope, $http, $compile) {

$scope.selectedMediaData = {};
$scope.datas = [];
var KeyNames = [];
$scope.GetDataForCrud = function () {
    $http({
        method: "get",
        url: "/Home/GetMediaPageDataForCrud",
        datatype: "json"
    }).then(function (response) {
        var jData = JSON.parse(response.data);
        var d = jData.ResultData;
        if (d.length > 0) {
            var keys = d[0];
            for (var key in keys) {
                KeyNames.push(key);
            }
        }
        $scope.keys = KeyNames;
        $scope.datas = jData.ResultData;
    }, function () {

    })
};

$scope.Edit = function (data) {
    $scope.selectedMediaData = angular.copy(data);
};

$scope.getTeamplate = function (data) {
    if (data.UID === $scope.selectedMediaData.UID)
    { return 'Edit'; }
    else
    { return 'Display'; }
};

$scope.AddNewRow = function () {
    var blankRow = '';
    for (key in KeyNames) {
        blankRow += KeyNames[key] + ":" + "\"\",";
    }
    $scope.datas.push({blankRow});
    console.log($scope.datas);
}


})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add New Row Like This :

```
$scope.AddNewRow = function () {
    var duplicateRow = {};
    duplicateRow = angular.copy($scope.datas[0]);
    for(v in duplicateRow){duplicateRow[v]="";}
    $scope.datas.push(duplicateRow);
};
```